# how to enable Pop up parent page scroll?

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

popup box will appear while clicking on a link.I need to enable the scroll for the parent page 
.For small screen laptops pop up is not able to view properly ,i cant do anything about the height of the popup . I want to enable the scroll .

```
.popup{
display: block;
z-index: 1002;
outline: 0px;
position: fixed;
height: auto;
width: 730px;
top: 209px;
left: 259px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pop up boxes are generally set to `position: absolute;` which are out of the document flow, so instead of using `fixed`, use `absolute`, even stackoverflow flag box uses absolute, as it doesn't get scrolled with the page, perhaps the browser shows scroll if your element is overflowing out of your defined width's if you set it to `position: absolute;`, just be sure you are not using `overflow: hidden;` may be for clearing floats, use `clear: both` instead and you should see the scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

Just add the CSS overflow property :

```
overflow-y : auto;
overflow-x : hidden;
```

Comment: i dont need scroll for popup , i need for parent page

Comment: after the popup is active also ,i want to scroll the page ,right now i cant able to scroll the page

Comment: Ok, my mistake. In fact, the popup overflowed the page. Is the height of the parent fixed?